# Credit card travel insurance for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, italy, insurance

I am applying through Italy for a Schengen visa. I have a complimentary travel insurance through my credit card. It is provided by 3rd party insurance company in Australia with which the bank has an agreement.

When I make a $500 transaction related to my travel on my credit card, I'm automatically eligible for travel insurance. It has unlimited medical benefits, as well as accident injury and repartriation costs.

Would this be a valid insurance for my visa?

My bank wouldn't provide any letter saying that I have this, as it is complimentary and only gives a Product Disclosure Statement (PDS). The insurer  gave me a generic letter that states it has an agreement with my bank and credit card and references the PDS.

The letter has my name on it and the countries to which I'm travelling, but no dates are mentioned, as it automatically gets activated when I leave Australia, provided that I meet the eligibility, as mentioned above.

Is this letter sufficient?

I will also provide a copy of my credit card and transaction history to show I have fulfulled the eligibility by spending 500 AUD on my travels.

Would this meet the travel insurance requirement, or is it safer to actually purchase a policy through an insurance provider?

Answer (score 1):

What the insurer has currently provided you would probably not be sufficient. Schengen Area countries, including Italy, requires non-EU citizens to have proof of health insurance which is specific to you and your travel plans. You would need a policy document that shows coverage in Italy and the Italian government requires a signed declaration from the insurance company, a certificate of coverage. This letter must show:

- that the coverage dates are for the entire trip;
- that the policy is valid in Italy;
- that it includes medical expenses, hospitalization, emergency medical evacuation, repatriation;
- that it provides at least 30,000 Euros in coverage.

Here's an example, which should appear on company letterhead:

**CONFIRMATION OF COVERAGE**

To whom it may concern:

We are pleased to confirm short term medical coverage under the ABC Travel Plan, insured by XYZ Insurance Company Ltd. This coverage is valid worldwide including the destination country listed below, as well as all other Schengen countries. It meets Schengen visa requirements. This plan will pay directly to providers when the Company is contacted and approves payment.

**Name**: Ned Kelly
**Policy Number**: ABC-123
**Home Country**: Australia
**Destination Country**: Italy
**Effective Date**: 27 March 1861
**Termination Date**: 11 November 1880
**Deductible**  $0
**Medical and Hospitalization Maximum** $50,000
**Emergency Medical Evacuation** $2,000,000
**Emergency Reunion** $15,000
**Repatrition of Remains** $1,000,000
**Pre-Existing Conditions** Covered for Unexpected Recurrence

Other limitations and exclusions do apply. Please see policy documents for details or contact us or your agent at the number below for any questions.

Sincerely,
Banjo Paterson